# `Art thou that prophet?` do they mean the Prophet Mohammad?

Tags: islam

John Chapter 1, verse 21 says:

```
19-And this is the record of John, when the Jews sent 
priests and Levites from Jerusalem to
ask him, Who art thou?
20-And he confessed, and denied not; but confessed,
I am not the Christ.
21-And they asked him, What then? Art thou Elias?
And he saith, I am not.
Art thou that prophet? And he answered, No.
```

Is the Prophet mentioned here Mohammad? if not, then why?

Comment: This can be a good question if you simply ask _"Does the prophet and Christ refer to same person?"_. But you are getting downvotes because you are trying to relate it with Mohammad. Please consider editing it.

Comment: no thanks , this is really my question because I've read that Jews asks `is he the prophet` agin when Mohammad born , and that makes sense if we match it with john 1 ,21 .

Comment: Jews asked "is he the prophet?" when Mohammad was born? Interesting. What is your source?

Comment: it's an Islamic source , prophet Mohammad's biography

Comment: The prophet here refers to the prophet Moses spoke about, asserting "God will raise up for you a prophet like me [Moses]".  Jesus is the prophet like Moses, as is well evidenced in the answer to this question:  http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/who-is-the-prophet-moses-mentioned-in-deuteronomy-1815

Comment: If that is right , then Jesus is Like Moses ,they both Prophets , not Gods . and that's what i do belive in .thanks

Comment: I apologize for the downvotes. You asked a valid question that deserves to be answered with respect. Deut. 18 9 - 22 deals with prophets in general. There will be a prophet in every generation. All will be less than Moses. Maybe you imply with your question that Mohammed was one of them. I would not imply anything like it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an Islamic interpretation of a Christian text - NOT ANYTHING ANY CHRISTIAN DENOMINATION HOLDS.

Comment: Christians and Muslims have very different opinions about Jesus and Mohammad. In general, [Christians do not and likely will never accept Mohammad as anything special.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33063/a-christian-view-of-mohammad/33065#33065)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this verse, one should first look at Deuteronomy 18:15-19 (KJV):

> 15 The LORD thy God will raise up unto thee a Prophet from the midst
>   of thee, of thy brethren, like unto me; unto him ye shall hearken; 16 According to all that thou desiredst of the LORD thy God in Horeb
>   in the day of the assembly, saying, Let me not hear again the voice of
>   the LORD my God, neither let me see this great fire any more, that I
>   die not. 
> 17 And the LORD said unto me, They have well spoken
>   that which they have spoken. 
> 18 I will raise them up a Prophet
>   from among their brethren, like unto thee, and will put my words in
>   his mouth; and he shall speak unto them all that I shall command him.
>   
> 19 And it shall come to pass, that whosoever will not hearken
>   unto my words which he shall speak in my name, I will require it of
>   him.

The "prophet" referred to in John 1:21 is the same Prophet that is spoken of in Deuteronomy 18. For many years, the Jews had been looking for this Prophet to come. This Prophet is Jesus Christ, the Son of God. Look at John 6:14 (KJV):

> 14 Then those men, when they had seen the miracle that Jesus did, said,
>   This is of a truth that prophet that should come into the world.

This was after Jesus did the great miracle of feeding 5,000 with 5 loaves and 2 fishes. These people basically said that the miracle that Jesus did gives evidence to Him as being the "prophet."

Check [this](http://www.answering-islam.org/Responses/Ghounem/john.htm) for more information.

Comment: Hohn said : ` am not the Christ.` then he says i'm not the prophet , how could they ask for christ twice ??

Comment: According to [this](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/gills-exposition-of-the-bible/john-1-21.html) some of the Jews believed that Jeremiah was the Prophet mentioned in Deut. 18:15 (also see Matthew 16:14, KJV).

Comment: I don't think so ,`he was not Jeremiah, nor any one of the old prophets risen from the dead` but the phrase `that prophet` means some one specified and unknown before , [else they would tell his name like `Elias`]

Comment: The Jews did not know who the "Prophet" in Deut 18. was. They may not have believed that the Messiah was the same as the "Prophet" mentioned. There could have been various men that they supposed the "Prophet" to be.

Comment: sorry but I think that `That` refers to specified [only one] person , and if there is no specified person mentioned ,then your answer[in the comments] seems meaningless.thanks

Comment: Even if "That" only refers to one person, it's still possible that the Jews did not believe that the Messiah and the Prophet were the same. Just because they may have believed that doesn't mean it's correct though.

Comment: thank you very much , yes it's only a possibility which may be encouraged by some other sources from the Bible or from Mohammad's Life , thanks again

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by others, many believe that `prophet` here refers to the Messiah expected by the Jews.

There is absolutely no reason to assume that the high priests were talking about someone who will come later on in the picture *outside their clan*. Being inside their clan is very important because, Jews believed that they are the Chosen people and the expected Messiah will be born among them. To be more specific they expected him to be born in the Jewish tribe of Juda (Genesis 49:10). They even knew where he will be born. (Matthew 2:4-6) They had lot of other prophecies about the Messiah. None of these prophecies matches the Islamic prophet. And hence it is not reasonable to consider that they were asking about him.

Historically unlike Jesus, the first person to claim that mohammad is the expected messiah is mohammad himself. No one else before him said anything of that sort.

Answer (score 1):

The "that prophet" is held by [a number of commentators](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/john/1-21.htm) to refer to Deuteronomy 18:15, where Moses said:

> **18**<sup>15</sup> : The LORD your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among you, from your brethren — him you shall heed.

John believed this to refer to the Messiah, and he answered No; he was not that prophet. Neither was Mohammed the Messiah.

Comment: but they asked him if he is the Christ[Messiah] before , so the `are you the prophet` is not about [Messiah] again , but about another person !

Comment: Not necessarily; they may simply have asked "Really?" and sought confirmation. I think I would recommend a question on MiYodeya about who the prophet foretold in Deut 18:15 is thought to be (but don't ask the leading question "Is it Mohammed?" -- just ask who it is).

Comment: does `not necessarily ` means maybe yes ?

Comment: No, it means that your assertion is wrong. While they **may** have asked about another person (and indeed they did: the prophet in Deut 18), **John** interpreted Deut 18 to refer to the Messiah, so he answered "No". What we can't know from this verse is who the priests thought Deut 18 referred to.

Answer (score 0):

John 1:1  KJV

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.

Mohammed did not come down from Heaven.

Comment: Is comming down from heaven is related to be a prophet !

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you thinks that the "prophet" and the "Christ" was different men, but the Holy Bible isn't interpreted as isolated verses. The Jews in that epoch failed in that matter too, because reading the prophecies you will infer that Jesus was:

- The Christ;
- The Prophet;
- The Son of David
- The Son of God;

Jesus did a lot of effort to make the Jews in that epoch understand this.