# Who did God talk to in Scripture?

Tags: prophets

I think I know at least 2: Abraham and Moses.

Are there any others? Were the Prophets just inspired or did any of them talk to God?

Comment: If your list of prophets includes Mohammed then you're asking on the wrong site.

Comment: If you want to limit the question to just the Christian bible, that would probably narrow it down, but including "recent times" makes the question far too broad and some Christians sects will definitely disagree

Comment: @curiousdannii, I edited my question, can you unblock the question and maybe change your downvote?

Comment: @curiousdannii, isn't Mohammed considered a prophet by christianity?

Comment: @PeterTurner,I corrected the question, can you unblock it?

Comment: @user157860 Of course not, Mohammed and Islam deny almost every important truth in Christianity. However even with this edit it's still too broad and a matter of opinion.

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33063/a-christian-view-of-mohammad. This older closed question might interest you

Comment: @PeterTurner, thanks for editing and lifting the hold, could you please balance the downvote that would entail banning from asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Adam and Eve** (in Genesis)
- **Cain** (in genesis)
- **Noah** (in Genesis)
- **Abraham** (in Genesis)
- **Satan** (in Job)
- **Job, Eliphaz, Bildad, and Zophar**, and possibly **Elihu** (in Job, from a whirlwind)
- **Moses** (in Exodus, Numbers, possibly Deuteronomy)
- **Aaron and Miriam** (in Numbers 12)
- **Samuel** (in 1 Samuel)
- **Elijah** (the still small voice of 1 Kings 19)
- **King Belshazzar** and his banquet guests (Daniel 5, if you consider writing to be speech: the finger writing on the wall)
- **the crowd** surrounding John the Baptist at Jesus' baptism
- **Paul** on the road to Damascus (in Acts)
- the **Apostle John** (in Revelation, technically a vision)

Some Theophanies are uncertain. Joshua met an angel with a sword which many believe to be the angel of the Lord, making it more than an angelic visitiation or a vision.

Many prophets begin their accounts saying that the Word of the Lord came to them. It is not spelled out in each case whether that was direct appearance, dream, vision, or strong inner voice, so we cannot say.

Fun fact: Of all the recorded instances where God spoke directly to people, his longest address was to Job.

Comment: What about Isaiah in chapter 6? Whether vision or not, it's the Lord speaking to him (dialogue). And I'd have to look it up, but I'm pretty sure that there are more in the house of Abraham that God talked to. And even then I think the list is not extensive.

Comment: I tried to avoid visions in my list and focus on theophanies. In Isaiah's case, some of the speakers were angels, not God speaking for himself, though in Isaiah 6 it does say he heard the voice of the Lord.

Answer (score 2):

All the people that Jesus "talked to" in the Gospels were "talked to" by God, since Jesus is God.  In addition, in Acts, Jesus appeared in a blinding apparition to Saul (who became Paul) and talked to him.  That is why we call Paul the "post-resurrection apostle."

Comment: hebrews 1:1-2 God, who at various times and in various ways spoke in time past to the fathers by the prophets, 2 has in these last days spoken to us by His Son, whom He has appointed heir of all things, through whom also He made the worlds;

Answer (score 1):

The audience at Jesus' baptism.

> While he was still speaking, a bright cloud overshadowed them, and
>   behold, a voice out of the cloud said, “This is My beloved Son, with
>   whom I am well-pleased; listen to Him!” Matt. 17:5